# Angular Momentum - Partial Derivatives

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, differentiation

A disk with some angular momentum $L$ is spinning with an angular velocity $\omega$ and radius $r$.

With conservation of angular momentum, as we reduce $r$ and increase in $\omega$, and therefore the rate of change of angular momentum is 0. However, I do not understanding how I can get to this conclusion mathematically from these first principles, where:

$$
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial r} = \, -2\frac{\omega}{r} 
$$

And also that
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial r} = \, -m\omega^2r
$$

I'm not very strong with partial derivatives and so a display of the procedure to get here would be very helpful!

Comment: How do you change the radius of a rotating disk?

Answer (score 0):

Angular momentum of a uniform rotating disk is

$$ L = ( \tfrac{m}{2} r^2 ) \omega $$

The change in angular momentum is

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  {\rm d} L & = \frac{\partial L}{\partial r} {\rm d}r +  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \omega} {\rm d}\omega \\
 & = \left(m r \omega \right) {\rm d}r + \left( \tfrac{m}{2} r^2 \right) {\rm d}\omega
\end{aligned} $$

To investigate conservation we set ${\rm d}L = 0$. The creates the a relationship between the change in rotation with the change in radius

$$\left(m r \omega \right) {\rm d}r =- \left( \tfrac{m}{2} r^2 \right) {\rm d}\omega $$

$$ \frac{{\rm d}\omega}{{\rm d}r} =- \frac{ \left(m r \omega \right)}{ \left( \tfrac{m}{2} r^2 \right)} = - \frac{2 \omega}{r} $$

The here being the negative sign (-) in front of the expression. It means when radius goes down, speed goes up. The *change* in the variables is the reverse direction always.